# Relationship between the symmetric difference of two sets and their intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How do we prove that the union of symmetric difference of two sets and their intersection is the same as the union of the two sets?

i.e. $(A\backslash B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\backslash A) = A\cup B$
where $A, B$ are two sets?

I know how it is obvious. But I want a rigorous proof from definitions of difference and union and intersection.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Don't use the `proof-writing` tag when your goal is to ask for a proof.

Comment: Such proofs amount to proving the equivalence of Boolean expressions. You can also use a Venn diagram, and IMO, this is rigorous enough.

Comment: Just show that each is a subset of the other. E.g., assume that $$x\in(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$ and by considering cases show that $x\in A\cup B$: either $x\in A\setminus B$, in which case ..., or $x\in A\cap B$, in which case ..., or ... .

Comment: In fact the question is about $(A\Delta B)\cup (A\cap B)$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust it seems reasonable to assume that either the OP already knows that $A\triangle B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$ or that the RHS is how "symmetric difference" was defined in the first place for the OP.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I can accept that, provided the expression is written $((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))\cup(A\cap B)$, and not as the union of three sets, even though the transformation is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed important to gain proficiency in setting up the logical structure of proofs like this (as Brian M. Scott comments). The statement to be proved is
$$
(A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A) = A\cup B,
$$
which is equivalent (by definition of set equality) to the pair of inclusions
$$
(A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A) \subset A\cup B \quad\text{and}\quad
A\cup B \subset (A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A).
$$
The proof of the first inclusion has this structure, by definition of subset:

> Assume that $x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A)$.
>
> ...
>
> Therefore $x\in A\cup B$ as desired.

And by definition of union, we can further expand this to:

> Assume that $x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A)$. In other words, assume that $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in B\setminus A$.
>
> Case 1: $x\in A\setminus B$. ... ... Therefore $x\in A\cup B$.
>
> Case 2: $x\in A\cap B$. ... ... Therefore $x\in A\cup B$.
>
> Case 3: $x\in B\setminus A$. ... ... Therefore $x\in A\cup B$.
>
> Therefore, in all cases, $x\in A\cup B$ as desired.

And the proof of the second inclusion has this structure:

> Assume that $x\in A\cup B$.
>
> ...
>
> Therefore $x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A)$ as desired.

In the course of filling in the "..." details of these proofs, you will indeed (explicitly or implicitly) be using the logical relationships described in Yves Daoust's answer. But this setting-up-the-structure skill is important for understanding why those logical relationships actually prove the statement you want to prove.

Comment: Thank you Greg! This is the answer I was looking for. I was trying to prove subset from both directions. But had got stuck both ways. Your case by case analysis and @Yves Daoust's truth table have given me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a:=x\in A, b:=x\in B$. The truth table for $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$ as a function of $ab=FF,TF,FT,TT$ is $F,T,T,F$, and that for $A\cap B$ is $F,F,F,T$. Now taking the union, $F,T,T,T$ is indeed the table for $A\cup B$.

[image]

Comment: I had not thought of doing a truth table. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were looking for a "computational" proof:

$$\underbrace{(A\backslash B)\cup(A\cap B)}_{A}\cup(B\backslash A)=A\cup (B\backslash A)=A\cup B.$$

In the first equality, I am using the fact that for any sets $A$ and $B$, we have
$$A=(A\backslash B)\cup (A\cap B).$$
Intuitively, this means that everything in $A$ either belongs to $B$ or it doesn't. For the second equality, it's just
$$A\cup (B\backslash A)=A\cup (B\cap A^c)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup A^c)=(A\cup B).$$

Comment: Thank you for this insight into simplification!